# Same data is displaying in all fragments using page Viewers to create pages

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have online database where I have stored "Title" for every page.
I am using Async Task to download the data from the server and in log statement I am able to see all the title string are retrieving properly.
Using FragmentStatePagerAdapter to create pages in MainActivity.
I am able to create pages successfully but all my pages have same data.

My MainActivity.java: which has pager adapter too.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager=null;
    int numFrag1;
    String title = "", getTitle= "";


    public class TitleDownload extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            CloudQuery query = new CloudQuery("CollegeFeeds");
            query.orderByAsc("updatedAt");
            query.include("imageTitle");

            try {
                query.count(new CloudIntegerCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(Integer integer, CloudException e) throws CloudException {

                        if(integer != null){

                           //int numFrag = integer;
                            noofFrag(integer);
                            //Log.i("no of fragments", String.valueOf(integer));
                            System.out.println("in background"+ integer);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (CloudException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                query.find(new CloudObjectArrayCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(CloudObject[] cloudObjects, CloudException e) throws CloudException {

                        if(cloudObjects != null){

                            //Log.i("no of fragments", String.valueOf(cloudObjects.length));

                            for (int i=0; i < cloudObjects.length; i++){

                               // Log.i("no of fragments", String.valueOf(cloudObjects.length));
                                title = cloudObjects[i].get("imageTitle").toString();
                                titleName(title);
                                Log.i("title", title);
                            }

                        }
                        if( e != null){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
            } catch (CloudException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return title ;
        }
    }
    public void noofFrag(int data){


         numFrag1 = data;

    }

    public void titleName(String titleData){

        getTitle = titleData;
        System.out.println("method title" + getTitle);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        CloudApp.init("qrhjtmypohec", "6e22fd4d-eef9-49b5-87a9-fba0f35075f9");

        new TitleDownload().execute();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
        //viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, );


        //actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            AttendanceResultFeed fragment = null;

            for (int i=0; i<4; i++){

                if(position == i){

                    fragment = new AttendanceResultFeed(position);
                    fragment.getTag();
                    //System.out.println("fragment tag" + fragment.getTag());
                    //fragment.getNumber(i);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("number", i);
                    bundle.putString("title", getTitle);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                }
                //return fragment;
                new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Log.d("info", "get count called");
            //numFrag1--;
            //Log.i("no of method(numFrag1) ", String.valueOf(numFrag1));
            new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            return 4;
        }



        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            if (position == 0){

                return "Attendance and Result";
            }

            if (position == 1){

                return "College Feeds";
            }

            if (position == 2){

                return "Branch Feeds";
            }
            return super.getPageTitle(position);
        }



    }

}
```

Fragment.java

```
public class AttendanceResultFeed extends Fragment {

    TextView textView, titleText;
    int number;
    String text= "";

    public AttendanceResultFeed(int position) {
        Log.i("position", String.valueOf(position));
    }


    public void getNumber (int data){

        number = data;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
           // Log.d("info", "in attandec frag on create First time");
        }else {
           // Log.d("info", "in attandec frag on create subsequent time");
        }

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_results_frag,container,false);

        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        titleText = (TextView )rootView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);


        number = getArguments().getInt("number",0);
        text = getArguments().getString("title");
        Log.d("info", String.valueOf(number));
        String num = String.valueOf(number);
        titleText.setText(text);
        textView.setText(num);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are setting your fragment's arguments with the same title in the following function:

```
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++){

            if(position == i){

                fragment = new AttendanceResultFeed(position);
                fragment.getTag();
                //System.out.println("fragment tag" + fragment.getTag());
                //fragment.getNumber(i);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("number", i);
                bundle.putString("title", getTitle);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            }
```

as you can see you put the same `getTitle` into the fragments arguments so actually all of your fragments get the same title.

I traced your code to see where `getTitle` get assigned and the assignment is in `titleName` function which is also called in another for loop, so basically `getTitle` always contains the last String that is assigned to it.

I'm not sure how your code is intended to work but here is a tip:

use an ArrayList to hold your titles:

```
//define this as a class member:
ArrayList<String> getTitle = new ArrayList<String>();

//change your titleName:
public void titleName(String titleData){

    getTitle.add(titleData);
    System.out.println("method title" + titleData);

}

//finally where you want to setArgument for your fragments use some logic to retrieve the titles, for example:
bundle.putString("title", getTitle.get(i));
```

Comment: I tried Your Solution, i am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: can you please suggest me what to do next?

Comment: @KrRakesh as I mentioned before, I don't know how your program works and it is just a suggestion, the error is probably because there is nothing in the getTitle when you try to get elements from it, it may give you some clue about your problem

Comment: i am able to see the contents of gettitle in the position from log statement (System.out: method title with position test 1) but i am not able to get it displayed from MyAdapter class.

Comment: @KrRakesh maybe your adapter gets called before filling your getTitle array